# Unable to insert column & rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel file in which I am unable to insert columns & rows. I am not getting any error message when I try to insert row/column. This file is not a big file with more data & formulas. Its very small file with size of 42KB.
I tried creating a new workbook & copy pasted the data fro this file. After pasting the data, I am getting same issue of unable to insert rows/columns
Can someone give some solutions for this.
Thanks,
Sangeetha

Comment: Please include [mcve]

Comment: Is the workbook/worksheet protected?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the column / row heading and choose (I)-Insert from the menu.  Check formulas after insertion/ deletion.